# R: Replace all values in column (NA and values) with mean of values

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with NA's and values in one column:

```
Day <- 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
Section <- 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
Value <- 1.2, 0.58, NA, 1.1, 0.8, NA
```

I want to get the mean of Values by Day and Section and replace all the values with it.

```
Day <- 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1
Section <- 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2
Value <- 0.89, 0.89, 0.89, 0.95, 0.95, 0.95
```

I tried but it obviously only adds the mean to the NA spaces. Any help would be appreciated.

```
mean_value <- df%>%  group_by(Day, Plate) %>%
  mutate(Value = ifelse(is.na(Value), mean(Value , na.rm=TRUE), Value ))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can just subset the non-NA elements to replace it

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
     group_by(Day, Plate) %>%
     mutate(Value = mean(Value[!is.na(Value)]))
```

Or use the `na.rm` in `mean`

```
df %>%
     group_by(Day, Plate) %>%
     mutate(Value = mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE))
```